# SharePoint 2010 - Web Analytics - Traffic works but Search does not

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am having a problem with the Web Analytics in Sharepoint 2010.

When I go to the Web Analytics Reports - Summary from Central Admin, I see that the Traffic Category shows results for Total Number of Search Queries and the other metrics. However, the Search Category displays 0 results for Total Number of Search Queries metric.

My search is up and running, and returns results accurately, so I'm having a hard time figuring out why the traffic works correctly but the searching does not. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the search information comes from the Usage and Processing service application. The database that this service corresponds to is - the WSS_Logging. I would investigate in that area and see if the WAP has the association and permissions.